# Groupby giving same aggregate value for all groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am trying to take mean of each group and trying to assign those to a new column in another dataframe but the first group's mean value is populating across all groups.

Below is my dataframe `df1`

```
level    value
CF        5
CF        4
CF        6
EL        2
EL        3
EL        1
EF        4
EF        3
EF        6
```

I am taking the mean of each group and saving it to a new column in another dataframe `df2`.

```py
df2['value'] = df1.groupby(['level'])['value'].transform('mean')
```

But this is giving me below result

```
level    value
CF        5.0
EL        5.0
EF        5.0
```

which should actually be

```
level    value
CF        5.0
EL        2.0
EF        4.333333
```

I get expected result if I am not saving the values to new columnn. I am not sure if this is correct way of assigning group values to new column.

Comment: We cannot answer unless you provide `df2`. Please give the output of `df1.to_dict('tight')` and `df2.to_dict('tight')` as [edit] to your question for reproducibllity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html), this is mostly useful when you want to assign to the **same** dataframe.

Here you need to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df2['value'] = df2['level'].map(df1.groupby(['level'])['value'].mean())
```

Comment: Should be `df2['value'] = df2['level'].map(df1.groupby(['level'])['value'].mean())
`

Comment: @RobertRobison yes of course. I hadn't checked due to the lack of reproducible input ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to do this:

```
df1.groupby(['level'])['value'].mean()
```

Output:

```
level
CF    5.000000
EF    4.333333
EL    2.000000
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Your original statement won't work because it returns a transformed value for each row of the original data frame. See stand-alone output without assigning the values:

```
print(df1.groupby(['level'])['value'].transform('mean'))
```

Output:

```
0    5.000000
1    5.000000
2    5.000000
3    2.000000
4    2.000000
5    2.000000
6    4.333333
7    4.333333
8    4.333333
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

So you get 3 rows of same value 5 because that is the first three rows being assigned to the `df2['value']`

Edited as per comments:

Depending on what your df2 is, you might need to merge the dataframes instead of assigning a column. For example:

```
# example df2
df2 = df1.groupby('level')['value'].sum()
df2 = df2.to_frame()

# merge with mean
df2.merge(df1.groupby('level')['value'].mean().rename('value2'), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Output:

```
      value    value2
level                 
CF        15  5.000000
EF        13  4.333333
EL         6  2.000000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `df1.groupby(['level'])['value'].mean()` will give me the expected result but while assigning this to new column `df2['value']=df1.groupby(['level'])['value'].mean()` I get NaN in all groups. That is why I used `transform`.

Comment: What is your `df2`? how have you defined it

Comment: `df2` is another dataframe where I have all groups with few other calculated columns.

Comment: Add that to the question as well `df2.to_dict()`. Because assigning it using transform will give different results per your expectation

Comment: @mockash Because based on how it is defined you might need to use a merge op instead of assignment

Comment: You mean to say I have to convert it to dictionary and assign values to the column as a key?

Comment: @mockash see my edit, again it will depend on what your `df2` is exactly defined as but a merge operation might be what you're looking for